# XNA load model incorrect

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, xna-4.0

I trying load model to XNA. This model is load, but textures are load incorrectly.
IMG:

[image]

Two wall is correct, but third is in stripes, and i don't now why.
In 3dsMax all walls are corently (in edit mode, and on render)
This is my function in Draw():

```cs
Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[capitol.Bones.Count];
capitol.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

foreach (ModelMesh mesh in capitol.Meshes)
{
     foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
     {
          effect.Alpha = 1.0f;
          effect.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
          effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f);
          effect.SpecularPower = 5.0f;
          effect.AmbientLightColor = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

          effect.DirectionalLight0.Enabled = true;
          effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = Vector3.One;
          effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f));
          effect.DirectionalLight0.SpecularColor = Vector3.One;

          effect.DirectionalLight1.Enabled = true;
          effect.DirectionalLight1.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
          effect.DirectionalLight1.Direction = Vector3.Normalize(new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f));
          effect.DirectionalLight1.SpecularColor = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

          effect.LightingEnabled = true;

          //effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
          effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] 
                   * Matrix.CreateRotationY(90f)
                   * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);

          effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
          effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(20.0f), aspectRatio, 1.0f, 50.0f);
    }
    // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
    mesh.Draw();
}
```

Load model:

```
brick = Content.Load<Model>("models\\brick_model");
```

Comment: The problem isn't in your draw function for sure. How do you load the model?

Comment: It seems that the problem isn't your code as you don't map the textures by yourself.

Comment: I load standard:
    Model brick;
 and in LoadContent()
     brick= Content.Load<Model>("models\\brick_model");

Comment: @Szymon the problem lies in the model

Comment: @Szymon Did you try to load it in a 3D modelling application and see how it looks like?

Comment: @Fuex looks good. In 3dsMax all walls are render correctly.

Comment: What model format is it?

Comment: I try import .fbx model, exported from 3dsMax

Comment: Is the texture sampling set to clamp, instead of wrap?